# Why does my Registrations#Update devise action not update all attributes in my `User` model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my `views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, class: "edit-user-form m-t" }) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>    
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input_field :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input_field :current_password, hint: "we need your current password to confirm your changes", placeholder: "current password", required: true %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input_field :password, autocomplete: "off", hint: "leave it blank if you don't want to change it", placeholder: "new password", required: false %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "confirm new password", required: false %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.association :school, collection:  School.where(school_type: [:college, :university]), prompt: "Choose a school", class: 'col-lg-4 form-control', label: false %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <%= f.button :submit, "Update", class: "btn btn-lg edit-account-update-button" %>
          </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

And this is my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :forbidden }
      format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, flash: { danger: exception.message }) }
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar, :school_id])
  end
end
```

The issue though is that it isn't updating the record, here is the log from that operation:

```
Started PUT "/users" for ::1 at 2016-11-02 19:22:59 -0500
Processing by DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xo445XVpElgDmfcjywZKEbsXIqZR/2Wgw==", "user"=>{"remove_avatar"=>"0", "avatar_cache"=>"", "email"=>"coach@test.com", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "school_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (4.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (9.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1, "avatar" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", 2016-11-03 00:22:59 UTC], ["avatar", "a1.jpg"], ["id", 7]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 139ms (ActiveRecord: 19.1ms)
```

Note that the `school_id` is set in the params, so we know it properly accepts the input from the form. But the `SQL UPDATE` statement, doesn't include `school_id`, so it doesn't actually save that info to the DB.

Also note that there are no `unpermitted params` messages in the log.

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

This is the `School.rb` model:

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users

  enum school_type: { high_school: 0, college: 1, university: 2 }
end
```

This is the `User.rb` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school    
end
```

Comment: Please post the code of respective models' .rb file

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Done. Refresh the question.

Comment: Why is the User class not inheriting `ApplicationRecord`?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Wasn't that changed many versions ago? I am running Rails-5 btw. I am pretty sure that's not the issue though.

Comment: Actually I am going through all of my models now, and they alternate between inheriting from `ApplicationRecord` and `ActiveRecord::Base`. Which is the correct one for Rails 5? What's the difference?

Comment: I'm using rails 5 as well since the beginning. Better to follow the convention. This should explain why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359527/why-rails-5-uses-applicationrecord-instead-of-activerecordbase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127238/discussion-between-akash-aggarwal-and-marcamillion).

Comment: But would that explain this one issue though?

Comment: I'm on chat, let's talk there

Comment: @AkashAggarwal See the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that your devise model User was inheriting `ActiveRecord::Base` instead of `ApplicationRecord` which is an abstract class in Rails 5. With the inheritance of latter, most of the gems which deal with models can and do modify the code of `ActiveRecord::Base` in their own context without affecting other models, which isn't possible if you inherit the former.

Source: [Why Rails 5 uses ApplicationRecord instead of ActiveRecord::Base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359527/why-rails-5-uses-applicationrecord-instead-of-activerecordbase)