# Rails 5.2 Undefined method belongs_to in inherited class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I recently upgraded to rails 5.2 and now I am getting an error in one of my models because the belongs_to method isn't being inherited by one of the subclass. Am I missing something obvious?

```
class B < A
  belongs_to :x
  belongs_to :y
end

class A < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :z
end

Error:
D#test_should_get_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `belongs_to' for B:Class
    app/models/B.rb:2:in `<class:QcQpcrSampleTest>'
    app/models/B.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    app/views/D/_form.erb:45:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_D__form_erb___2546218964114172504_70133388141640'
    app/views/D/_form.erb:22:in `block in ...
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:78:in `set_time_zone'
    test/controllers/D_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:DTest>'
```

Comment: Did you create application_record.rb in app/models?

Comment: @Vasilisa No, is this necessary? ApplicationRecord is just the rails 5 replacement for ActiveRecord https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359527/why-rails-5-uses-applicationrecord-instead-of-activerecordbase

Answer (score 0):

You're inheriting class A from ApplicationRecord, but your app have no idea - what is it. Create application_record.rb in app/models and place code inside it:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

It's OK now, all your models inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and have all association methods

Comment: I have this file in my project and am still getting the error